# How to call getSupportFragmentManager() to acquire an instance of FragmentManager

Tags: android

I'm trying to create timepicker as referred to the Android Developer guide. But
getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined. This is my first time developing android app, please help me.

```
public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }
```

Comment: what is your min sdk in manifest? imported these?   import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

Comment: you class got to extend FragmentActivity, not Activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

import the below and extend `FragmentActivity`

```
  import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Quote from the above link

If your app supports versions of Android lower than 3.0, be sure that you call `getSupportFragmentManager()` to acquire an instance of `FragmentManager`. Also make sure that your activity that displays the time picker extends `FragmentActivity` instead of the standard Activity class.

Answer (score 1):

you class got to extend FragmentActivity, not Activity

```
public class YourClass extends FragmentActivity {
....
```